# UICollectionViewCell content wrong size on first load

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a added a `UICollectionView` to my `UIViewController` and have made a custom cell for it.

I set the size of the cell using the `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` method and set each cell to be `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width/2` in both height and width. So essentially, each cell is half the screen wide and this same length in height.

I then have an `UIImageView` inside the cell with each edge pinned to its relative edge of the cell so that the image view fills the cell. I also have a `UILabel` that is centred both vertically and horizontally in the cell.

However on first load, the cell is the correct size but the content is much smaller in a tiny square in the top left. (Seen in the image below, I have set the cell's contentView background color to green and the imageView background color to red).

[image]

Then after scrolling down a little bit (and I assume a reusable cell being dequeued) all of the cells are fine (and remain fine after scrolling back up).

[image]

What is causing the content to not be constrained properly on first load?

**UPDATE**

Some of the code from my `UIViewController`:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("PrevDrawCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? PrevDrawCell

        if cell == nil {
            cell = PrevDrawCell()
        }

        cell!.drawVC = self
        cell!.imageShortCode = self.tempImageURLs[indexPath.row]

        // Pull image (async) and set after download
        cell!.setupImage()

        cell!.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        cell!.coverView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        cell!.dateLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 26)
        cell!.dateLabel.text = "\(self.tempImageURLs.count-indexPath.row)/9"

        return cell!
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let size = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width/2
        return CGSize(width: size, height: size)
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsetsZero
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```

Comment: Show `UIViewController`

Comment: You mean show the code for the `UIViewController`?

Comment: I've added some of the code for the `UICollectionView`. Not sure what exactly you want to see?

Comment: Almost looks like the default 100x100px cell size. If you use the view debugger in Xcode, is it the cell itself or the contentView that still uses the default size? What happens if you call layoutIfNeeded after you set everything on your cell?

Comment: @DepartamentoB In the view hierarchy debugger when I select the actual cell itself it is the size of the green background, not the little red square. Also, just tried calling `cell.layoutIfNeeded()` just before I `return cell` in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method and this solves it! Is this a good thing to be doing here? What exactly is it doing and are there any downsides? Should it be called in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` where I have put it or somewhere else instead?

Comment: I think it only layouts *IF* needed, if not it doesn't. I wouldn't worry about it too much, but theoretically there might be places where performance might be affected negatively if it really does the whole layout twice. I'll add it as an answer so the next person looking for this sees an accepted answer.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

It looks like it still retains it's 100x100px basic size for the contentView while the cell itself gets the right size already. You can force the layout to reset adding the following line just before you return the cell:

```
cell?.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Use **layoutIfNeeded()** to solve any size related issues which you may face when cell or view is loading for the first time, unless you call **layoutIfNeeded()** it will wait for the next draw cycle to apply the size related changes, however calling **layoutIfNeeded()** immediately applies those changes! Little code, Larger effect !!

Comment: in my case when I scroll my collection view down, cells looks good, but if I scroll up cell size is very large and readjusts it's size on scroll.@DhavalNena

Comment: For some reason this is something that I never got to work. I am using full autolayout with dynamic cell heights, might be incompatible with this solution? Even doing layoutIfNeeded, when I inspect the frame size of the cell it always responds with the size set in IB. Usually only after scrolling back the correct autolayouted size is responded.

Comment: For me, the issue was the wrong first size of the container view while the cell's frame was right! Now with layoutIfNeeded it works great! Thank you! :)

Comment: I tried all of the solutions but none of them worked for me, I was giving larger cell size in flowLayout.estimatedItemSize then my cell size, fixing it fix the problem for me

Comment: @MuhammadAli I have never had this problem again since 2015, automatically sized cells work well enough for me so far.

Answer (score 45):

What worked for me was changing `Estimate Size` on the Collection View from Automatic to None.

[image: collection view estimate size]

Comment: I searched one hour for this solution!

Comment: This fixed the problem with my cell size, but the content views are still laying out at the default size.

Comment: This is the correct answer, do that and also change min spacing values

Comment: This worked for me like a charm!!! I have been finding a solution since two hours.

Comment: @bugloaf facing the same issue as your comment, did you find a solution to this ?

Comment: Thanks,thanks thanks, I spend 2 hour for this answer

Comment: Saved the day. I wasted a whole day to figure out. Bravo!!!!! @trishcode

Answer (score 6):

I had once similar problem (content of my cell was not fitting cell even with correct autolayout). The bug was caused by not calling 
`super.layoutSubviews()` in overriden function layoutSubviews() that was in Cell's class.

Comment: I never got [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32596125/129202) to work, and I have not overridden layoutSubviews.

Comment: This solved my problem. In my case it was in a UICollectionViewCell, more specifically.

Comment: And just to repeat, calling it "in the wrong order" can be key.  And note that this seems to apply also to the table/collection view as such - and/or the cells as such.

Answer (score 4):

For those using Storyboard + AutoLayout, and choosing which constraints are active at runtime:

When using dequeueReusableCell, on first load, the cell is created but its view has not been initialised, so the constraint changes aren't saved - whatever you have set in Storyboard is used. Solution for me was to update the constraints after the view has loaded:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    adjustIconWidths()
}
```

Comment: If you are using the autolayout, what constraints are you updating?

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I need to assign the height of the cell equal to the height of collectionView. But the height of the collection view depends on the size of the screen.
So inside sizeForItemAt delegate

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: currentScreenWidth, height: collectionView.frame.height)
}
```

**To make this work I need to call reloadData function from viewDidLayoutSubviews**

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    mycollection.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem, not exactly the same, but could help somebody.
I did a override prepareForReuse without calling `super.prepareForReuse()` in cell. So, when I use UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout with .estimated(100) for cells height, I got weird behaviour on device rotation: if rotate without scrolling, just after view appear, and then scroll - you will have cells with estimated height (100), not updated with the layout.
So, try to check this part :

```
 override func prepareForReuse() {
     super.prepareForReuse()
 }
```

Comment: This!!! I was working on code someone else had written and didn't notice they'd forgotten to call `super.prepareForReuse()`. Was having all kinds of self-sizing issues and I couldn't figure out what was going on. Once I discovered the missing `super` call, everything worked.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the great tip by vin047.

In our case I found that the super-call-order issue was the problem.

But **with the overall table view** (or collection view).  Not in the cell as such.

## Works:

```
class UnusualCollectionView: UICollectionView {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
    }
```

## Fails very erratically, particularly on first appearance:

```
class UnusualCollectionView: UICollectionView {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }
```

The problem caused some profoundly erratic behavior.  For example, the 12th cell (no really) was always displaced a long way vertically.  Always the 12th cell!  Who knows?

vin047 saved the day here, bravo.

Answer (score 0):

hey guys if still anyone not able to set the content size because the autoresizing cells, you can add this to you collection view and you can get the content size

*here scrolling makes the view get the correct content size so make your CollectionView scrollable or disable it, in both cases you will get the content size after loading the data in cells

```
`XCollectionView.isScrollEnabled = true/false`
```

*then reload the data from datasource

```
`XCollectionView.reloadData()`
```

*then call layoutneeded

```
`XCollectionView.layoutIfNedded()`
```

*then you can check, the content size will be equal to your content

```
`XCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height`
```

*now set the height of your collection view to the content height and you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was reloading the Collection View in viewWillLayoutSubviews.

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
  
}
```