# Why the UIImageView does not fill the entire CollectionViewCell even I have all the constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, autolayout, uicollectionview

I have a horizontal `UICollectionView`, and each cell holds a `UIImageView`. When I position the UIImageView inside the cell:

**the storyboard looks like this**(notice the `UIImageView` takes the entire space of the `UICollectionViewCell` with an identifier postInnerCell)[image]

I think I have set the constraint using autoLayout correctly, with each side of the `UIImageView` pined to the margins of the `UICollectionViewCell`. **Like this**:

[image]

When I ran the simulator, however, it looks like this:[image]

The image does not fill up the entire space of the `collectionViewCell`(with the gray background color). The the content mode of the `UIImageView` is set to be aspect fill in the interface builder.

Here is my view hierarchy:
[image]

**Note that the entire `UICollectionView` is a cell of the tableView(Basically, what I try to accomplish is each row of the tableView is a horizontal slider). I'm not sure that's the problem. Anyone have any idea about why such a issue occurs. **

Comment: maybe you need to check your view content mode,  must be aspect fill

Comment: @ReinierMelian, you meant the content mode of the imageView, I set it already, as mentioned in my question

Comment: can you add some code to see what is happening? sorry for my previous comment

Comment: I think you should tick the clip subviews option on the post Inner cell (the cell of the collection view)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that I need to re-layout the subview by calling `cell.layoutIfNeeded()` before I return the cell in the `collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` method. Thanks to the contribution of answer here [UICollectionViewCell content wrong size on first load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32593117/uicollectionviewcell-content-wrong-size-on-first-load)

Answer (score 0):

Set `Content hugging priority` of the image view to `Low (250)`.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, the content view of the cell will resize without triggering AutoLayout, so you have to manually either trigger a layout pass (e.g. `.needsLayout = true` or add constraints from the content view to the cell

Comment: what do you mean by adding constraints from the content view to the cell, you mean the constraint between the contentView to the collectionview?

Comment: The view hierarchy you have is: Collection View > Cell(s) > Content View > Image View. I'm talking about constraints from the content view to the cell. Try the view debugger to see what I'm talking about.